# JWT Access token and Refresh token security

Tags: security, jwt, token, refresh

I'm creating an app using for front-end Reactjs and for back-end SpringBoot(REST).

I want to use JWT tokens for security. Because of the security issues that stealing a JWT refresh token may imply, I thought to ask you if the following scenario is a valid one:

- Back-end

  - on login create access-JWT and refresh-JWT
  - in both in payload section set the same unique UUID(so I create a "link" between them).
  - save the hashCode of refresh-JWT in DB (for future validity check)
  - return as response in body access-JWT and as cookie refresh-JWT.
- Front-end

  - Store access-JWT in local storage
  - Store refresh-JWT as cookie

Now on every request from front-end I will aspect both tokens (access-JWT in header and refresh-JWT as cookie). I check both of them if they have same unique UUID. If they do I will continue the validating process for them.

Doing this I'm hopping to eliminate XSS and CSRF attacks assuming that those won't be done simultaneous. So if access-JWT is stolen the attacker won't have refresh-JWT and vice-versa.

Please share your thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid inventing your own authentication/session management scheme since tiny details can undermine the security of the whole system.

Quoting from Auth0's [Which OAuth 2.0 flow should I use?](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use)

> Also, it should be noted that Implicit Grant does not return a Refresh Token because the browser cannot keep it private (read the SPAs and Refresh Tokens panel for a workaround).

I would suggest going with a standard OpenID Connect (or OAuth 2.0) flow - in your case the **implicit flow**.